# If after my app quits I save something to Core Data, it crashes on the following launch every time. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When my app goes to the background, I call this method:

```
- (void)saveArticlePosition {
    self.article.position = self.position;

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    [managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

With a notification from `applicationDidEnterBackground`. However, on the next app launch, I get this error:

```
[ReadingViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x844fe40
```

Caused from this line in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Which is a part of this bigger portion:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    RootViewController *controller = (RootViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    ...
```

What exactly is going wrong? All I can think is that the `controller` object there is of type `RootViewController` while I saved to Core Data in `ReadingViewController`, but how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an instance variable called managedObjectContext on your ReadingViewController?

I ask, as in your save method, you don't use an instance variable to get the context, but look up the context via the app delegate.

That's what the error message:

```
[ReadingViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

means. You have tried to call a method on an instance of ReadingViewController, and ReadingViewController does not have a method with that name. (you would expect to have either implemented a method setManagedObjectContext: in ReadingViewController, or have a property called managedObjectContext defined within it).

If you store the context in your app delegate, then you don't need to save it into your ReadingViewController, especially if whenever you need it, you look it up via the app delegate.

Comment: How do I make it use the method from the AppDelegate rather than in ReadingViewController then? I was trying to have everything operate out of the AppDelegate.

Comment: What I was getting at is the line `controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` looks unnecessary - if you don't have a `managedObjectContext` property on your `ReadingViewController`, delete that line.

Comment: And your save method **already** is accessing the context via the app delegate. It looks like you are mixing up two styles of accessing the context. You can either set it up in your app delegate and **pass it** down to your view controllers (style wise I would argue this is the better/cleaner method), OR, you can access it directly by asking the app delegate for it (which is what your save method is already doing). You are trying to do both, do one or the other - either method will work, both together is what is confusing you.

Comment: I think I'm getting what you're saying, but if my `self.article` object is an object from Core Data, how do I save the new value I gave it into the persistent store without using some sort of `save` method after I alter the value? Are you suggesting I just do the "setting" line? And if so, how am I using the AppDelegate at all? I guess I'm just confused *how* I'm supposed to be using the AppDelegate in this scenario, as I just want to save it to the persistent store. Apologies if I'm being dense as oak right now, I'm pretty new to Core Data.

Comment: And when you say it would be better style to set it up in your app delegate and pass it down to your view controllers, what exactly do you mean by this? Can you expand on that at all? In `viewDidLoad` create a view-controller-specific version of the `managedObjectContext`?

Comment: Your line `NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];` in your save method looks up the managedObjectContext already setup in your app delegate. The line `controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` in your application:didFinishLaunching is therefore redundant, and is also the cause of your crash. Just get rid of it. Use your save method as it is. Worry about style once you get to grips with Core Data. I get the impression you've taken code from two different sources and are mixing it up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34409/discussion-between-doug-smith-and-rob-glassey)

Answer (score 0):

According the error message, the object that you get from navigationController.topViewController is really a ReadingViewController even though you cast it to RootViewController. ReadingViewController doesn't have a managedObjectContext property it seems.

I'm also not sure why you are trying to set that property anyway, because the code indicates that you get the managedObjectContext directly from the AppDelegate instead of a local property in saveArticlePosition.

Comment: I'm trying to do everything out of the AppDelegate. I'm in ReadingViewController and an object in Core Data that I have reference to needs a value changed. What am I doing wrong to make it not operate out of AppDelegate? I just want to save something to Core Data.

Comment: Maybe you are getting confused/fixated on the saving. The crash isn't happening at the save, but in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. I presume you've set up your managedObjectContext (self.managedObjectContext) elsewhere - the unnecessary bit seems to be the line where you are setting it to your view controller. If you don't have a property or instance variable on that object, there is no point setting that value there. Your save method as written does not rely on the managedObjectContext being passed to it, as you are accessing it **directly** via the app delegate .